# what is the difference between "She is getting crazy" and "She is going crazy"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

What is the difference between "**get**" and "**go**" when expressing states?

For example, "**She is getting crazy**" vs "**She is going crazy**".

and "**I'm getting online to check my Facebook**" vs "**I'm going online to check my Facebook**"?

According to my research, it seems that "**get**" can be used for both positive and negative feelings, for example, "**she is getting upset**" and "**she is getting excited**".

And "**go**" is normally used for negative feelings, for example, "**She went insane**"

However, "**go online**" doesn't carry native meanings.

Also, "**get**" is often used in continuous tenses and "**go**" might not be used in continuous tenses, but I am not sure.

Finally, I think we can only remember phrases by phrases, there is no way to make sense of them.

Comment: We usually use *get* or *become* with states. *Go crazy* (or other words suggesting insanity such as *insane, mad, berserk*) seems to me to be a special usage. I think _go online_ is a different usage of _go_. When you 'go online', you are putting yourself in a metaphorical 'place'.

Answer (score 1):

Q. what is the difference between “She is getting crazy” and “She is going crazy”?

I would suggest there is not only a difference between get an go (as explained below) but even with the use of crazy.

crazy adjective (**NOT SENSIBLE**)
crazy adjective (**ANGRY**)

crazy; **mentally ill**:

---

"**She is getting crazy**" = She is getting emotional

Here I would suggest the meaning is not the same as going crazy =  insane I would suggest getting crazy means getting a bit wild, excited, or possibly annoyed. However without context it is difficult to determine.

"**I'm getting online to check my Facebook**" = I'm preparing to be online to check my Facebook

**get** verb (**EMOTION**) or get verb (BECOME ILL WITH)

**get** verb (**PREPARE**) get verb (START TO BE)

---

"**She is going crazy**". = She is **becoming** crazy

"**I'm **going online** to check my Facebook**"? = I'm to **use the internet** to check my Facebook

go verb (**BECOME**)

go verb (**START**) to **start doing** or **using** something:

[All Ref CED  crazy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/crazy)